# Reading your git repo within a Heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I'm using [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) to read an application's git repository from within the application. This works nicely locally. I pushed the application up to Heroku. It appears Heroku doesn't keep the repository anywhere accessible to the application.

Is there anyway to instruct Heroku to deploy the repository with the application or are there any other tricks I might use to read the contents of an application's repository from within the application on Heroku?

Comment: Have a look at the [article about the slug-compiler](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) on Heroku, it should give you an idea of what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Matt. Unfortunately, it clearly says the .git directory is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You would not have access to the git repo from the application sandbox in Heroku. I cannot see why you would need that, but this could be a [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: I'm new to both ruby as well as git. For a fun application I thought I would take a directory of markdown files I have, add them to a repo along with a small app which would read the repo and transform the markdown files into a tabbed html page. So I'm using the repo like a db as an experiment. Can you tell me more about the sandbox in Heroku? Other ideas?